Smoothing stat_density_2d_filled in R to make distribution normal
I have a stat_density_2d_filled that looks like this (image provided), and the code looks like:
stat_density_2d_filled(aes(fill = ..level..), bins = 5, contour_var = "ndensity")

enter image description here
How can I smooth these out so they are essentially circles layered on top of each other rather than the blobs they currently are
I've tried adjusting the number of bins and Ive tried various other ggplot density functions

geom_contour_filled() does it!

Set the adjust argument in stat_density_2d_filled.

adjust A multiplicative bandwidth adjustment to be used if 'h' is 'NULL'. This makes it possible to adjust the bandwidth while still using the a bandwidth estimator. For example, adjust = 1/2 means use half of the default bandwidth.

This lets you adjust the kernel bandwidth by a chosen factor. A factor greater than 1 means a wider kernel, smoothing out the estimated density function and leading to simpler contours. Play around with the value of adjust until you get the desired results.
